# UINavigationController pushViewController - Keyboard lagging on Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view controller that has a keyboard (I use becomFirstResponder in my viewDidLoad method to achieve this). This view controller also has a button which triggers an IBAction that uses pushviewcontroller to load another viewcontroller. This works fine but my problem is the keyboard seems to animate away after the content in the first view controller. So essentially it is still there when the next view controller loads for a few seconds and then slides out of the scene....Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view controller with the Text Fields hook up UITextFieldDelegate and do

```
myTextField.delegate = self;
```

then implement it in the controller -

```
// In Header
UITextField *currentField;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *currentField;

// In Implementation    
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.currentField = textField;
}
```

So when you are ready to push your new view controller you just -

```
[self.currentField resignFirstResponder];
```

or simpler yet resign all of your text fields

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is resign the keyboard, and fire an NSTimer which will call a method that will push to the next view controller after a fixed amount of time. You can play around with the time the NSTimer fires to get the effect you want. Hope that helps!